# How long can I expect the average drama or action sequence to last with 5-6 Players?

Tags: time, pacing, 7th-sea-2e

I am currently planning a oneshot to try out 7th Sea for the first time. My players will be experienced roleplayers, but 7th Sea will be new for them, too.

With that in mind, my question is the following:
**How much Time can I expect Drama- and Action Sequences to take, on average, with the following parameters:**

- 5 to 6 players with RPG experience that are new to 7th Sea
- characters are pregenerated by me, and their stats are spread out a bit, so you can calculate with an average Number of around 5-6 dice for most Sequences
- I am confident in my ability to Cut freeform roleplaying outside of Drama and Action Sequences, so Everything outside of those is of no concern

Comment: If I need to specify more parameters to narrow the expected time a sequence will take down a bit more, I will. There might be factors I do mit know about.

Comment: Is there something particular about 7th Sea that makes this question remotely answerable?

Comment: Both Drama and action sequences are well defined in the system. I was unsure about it at first, too, but after running the question idea by some people in chat, we came to the conclusion that it is answerable from experience.

Comment: Get the quick start PDF and run through that starter adventure that comes with it for the first session with the understanding for everyone that it is so they get used to the rules and such. That will give you a better idea how long your group will take as it varies by group and will allow you to iron out the kinks for the group with the understanding that is what the session is for. Do chargen or something afterwards and people that finish early leave early, people that take longer you can help without delaying game start.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of variables to this scenario.  7th Sea 2E tries to meter out the action with bidding raises, although by and large I don't see the mechanic having an affect on things more so than other systems.  For a starting group, **I would expect any given encounter to last about an hour - social or combat**.  While every game's combat has stalling points based on the give and take, a lot of combats are decided before they start if only one side is formally trained (there are homebrews for partial "sword school" training, I believe some of them were put into later errata).  A starter level game expects about two raises a round for a reasonably trained individuals, and as long as you avoid certain Virtues that create monstrous dice pools, the game should flow.

Your biggest stalling moments will be players figuring out more uses to raises than for the most obvious things like picking an attack.  The game is designed to be more free form by even making NPC generation more spontaneous, and most actions resolved by predetermined success from rolls every round.  Your players having experience will be incredibly helpful so that they will have a better understanding of how to pace the more "cinematic" bits that don't need rolls.  7th Sea 2e is an original system, which may trouble some players who like to metagame their actions towards their best rolls, but ultimately it will be up to you to have cues and opportunities at the ready (especially in the beginning) to show them what sorts of things they can do here versus other games.